# How to connect SqlAlchemy to Azure SQL database

Tags: python, sql-server, sqlalchemy, azure-sql-database

I am trying to connect to my Azure SQL Database by using SqlAlchemy. Currently, when I try to use the code below I get the following errors. Currently Error 1 listed below, but I have also gotten the others while trying different approaches.

Error 1 (if I leave the code as written below):

> (pyodbc.Error) ('IM010', '[IM010] [Microsoft][ODBC Driver Manager] Data source name too long (0) (SQLDriverConnect)')
> (Background on this error at: https://sqlalche.me/e/20/dbapi)
> pyodbc.Error: ('IM010', '[IM010] [Microsoft][ODBC Driver Manager] Data source name too long (0) (SQLDriverConnect)')

Error 2:

> pyodbc.InterfaceError: ('IM002', '[IM002] [Microsoft][ODBC Driver Manager] Data source name not found and no default driver specified

Error 3: This happens on the 'engine = ...' line if I don't use urllib

> ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10

What is incorrect with my code, and how do I connect to my Azure SQL Database with SqlAlchemy?

```py
import pyodbc
import time
import GW_PDR_Queries   as qu
import pandas           as pd
import sqlalchemy
import urllib

server   = 'myserver.database.windows.net'
database = 'myDatabase'
username = 'myUsername'
password = 'myPassword'   
# driver   = '{ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server}'
driver   = 'Driver={SQL Server}'
# connection_string = 'DRIVER='+driver+';SERVER=tcp:'+server+';PORT=1433;DATABASE='+database+';UID='+username+';PWD='+ password
connection_string = driver+';SERVER=tcp:'+server+';PORT=1433;DATABASE='+database+';UID='+username+';PWD='+ password
# connection_string = username + '@' + server + ':' + password + '@' + server

connection_string = urllib.parse.quote_plus(connection_string)

#'DRIVER={SQL Server};SERVER=yoursqlAzureServer.database.windows.net,1433', user='yourName@yoursqlAzureServer', password='Password', database='DBName'
engine = sqlalchemy.create_engine('mssql+pyodbc://'+ connection_string)
# engine = sqlalchemy.create_engine(connection_string)

query = 'SELECT * FROM panel.panel_table'

with engine.begin() as conn:
    df = pd.read_sql_query(sql=text(query), con=conn)
```

Comment: `'Driver={SQL Server}'` will fallback to one of the SQL NAtive Client libraries on Windows. SNAC hasn't been updated since SQL Server 2012 days so it won't work with Azure. Do you have ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server installed? Or ODBC Driver 18 for SQL Server?

Comment: Also, `PORT` isn't an ODBC connection string property. If you're needing to connect to an SQL Server instance that's not listening on the default tcp/1433 port then you include the port number inside the `Server` property, e.g.: `Server=tcp:serverNameOrIpAddress,2544;`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To connect sqlalchemy to Azure SQL Database Follow below code:

> pyodbc.Error: ('IM010', '[IM010] [Microsoft][ODBC Driver Manager] Data source name too long (0) (SQLDriverConnect)')

If your username or password contain **@** make sure convert it in to `%40`

> pyodbc.InterfaceError: ('IM002', '[IM002] [Microsoft][ODBC Driver Manager] Data source name not found and no default driver specified

To resolve above error, make sure you have proper driver installed locally.

**My sample Code:**

```py
import urllib
from sqlalchemy import create_engine,text
import pandas as pd

server   = 'servername.database.windows.net'
database = 'databasename'
username = 'username'
password = 'password!'   
driver   = '{ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server}'

conn = f"""Driver={driver};Server=tcp:{server},1433;Database={database};
Uid={username};Pwd={password};Encrypt=yes;TrustServerCertificate=no;Connection Timeout=30;"""

params = urllib.parse.quote_plus(conn)
conn_str = 'mssql+pyodbc:///?autocommit=true&odbc_connect={}'.format(params)
engine = create_engine(conn_str, echo=True)

query = 'SELECT @@version'

with engine.connect() as connection:
    df = pd.read_sql_query(sql=text(query), con=connection)
print(df.to_markdown())
```

**Here I am querying SQL version from SQL and storing it into dataframe.**

[image]