# Getting ODBC Driver 17 error while connecting to azure SQL

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, azure-sql-database, pyodbc

I'm getting the following error while connection my code to azure SQL from local machine (windows) and also when deployed to azure function (python/linux)

> sqlalchemy.exc.OperationalError: (pyodbc.OperationalError) ('08001',
> '[08001] [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server]TCP Provider: A
> non-recoverable error occurred during a database lookup.\r\n (11003)
> (SQLDriverConnect); [08001] [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 17 for SQL
> Server]Login timeout expired (0); [08001] [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 17
> for SQL Server]A network-related or instance-specific error has
> occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. Server is not
> found or not accessible. Check if instance name is correct and if SQL
> Server is configured to allow remote connections. For more information
> see SQL Server Books Online. (11003)')

I'm able to connect to the SQL server using SQL Server management studio

my sample code for connecting to SQL server

```
from sqlalchemy import create_engine
connection_string = "mssql+pyodbc://user:password@azuresqlserver.database.windows.net/mydatabase?driver=ODBC+Driver+17+for+SQL+Server" 
self.engine = create_engine(connection_string, pool_size=100, max_overflow=20)
self.engine.connect()
```

- I have SQL server (2019) installed on my machine, yet installed ODBC Driver
  17 and 18
- Downgraded python from 3.11 to 3.9 ( [similar issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76764452/azure-functions-cant-open-lib-odbc-driver-17-for-sql-server))
- using SQL SErver management studio, i'm able to connect to the SQL
  server from my windows machine
- using VS Code to deploy on azure fuction (Serverless) hence docker image is not supported

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please add the following items on the connection string:

```
;Encrypt=yes;TrustServerCertificate=no;Connection Timeout=30;"
```

Below a full example on how to connect from SqlAlchemy that I extracted from [this other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76974175/how-to-connect-sqlalchemy-to-azure-sql-database).

```
import urllib
from sqlalchemy import create_engine,text
import pandas as pd

server   = 'servername.database.windows.net'
database = 'databasename'
username = 'username'
password = 'password!'   
driver   = '{ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server}'

conn = f"""Driver={driver};Server=tcp:{server},1433;Database={database};
Uid={username};Pwd={password};Encrypt=yes;TrustServerCertificate=no;Connection Timeout=30;"""

params = urllib.parse.quote_plus(conn)
conn_str = 'mssql+pyodbc:///?autocommit=true&odbc_connect={}'.format(params)
engine = create_engine(conn_str, echo=True)

query = 'SELECT @@version'

with engine.connect() as connection:
    df = pd.read_sql_query(sql=text(query), con=connection)
print(df.to_markdown())
```

Comment: turns out my sqlalchemy was updated from 1.x to 2.x
Connectionstring changes have been introduced.
https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/20/changelog/migration_20.html

Comment: Thank you for sharing that documentation.